# php-fpm does not work exec, system, shell_exec, only CLI

Tags: nginx, exec, php, openbsd

`php-fpm`, `nginx` exec when in use `.phpfiles()` `shell_exec()` `system()` works fine from the command line.

Example when works well:

```
#php myphp.php
```

`myphp.php` contains:

```
<?php
exec('ping -c 3 google.com', $output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

But if I put on my browser `http://localhost/myphp.php`, it does not work anymore.

Any ideas?
I edit

I made a file with the following contents:

```
#cat info.php

<?php
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}
    phpinfo();
?>
```

In my browser, print

> exec is enabled, y php info..

I made a file with the following contents:

```
#cat info.php

<?php 
// Check for safe mode
if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
    // Do it the safe mode way
echo "Do it the safe mode way";
}else{
    // Do it the regular way
echo "Do it the regular way";
}

?>
```

In my browser, print

> Do it the regular way

Did not I like to know if I'm in a jail?

In my php ini

```
#cat /etc/php-5.5.ini
```

safe_mode not shown, or ON or OFF.
simply does not exist

Comment: Check `phpinfo` for the environment setup, set PATHs, if exec is disabled, or FPM runs in a chroot.

Comment: and also safe_mode, if it is on, system calls are disabled

Comment: System calls have to be enabled in PHP.ini for non cli

Comment: It's behind `nginx` with unknown configuration, answer is pretty confusing:) Please make it clear if `nginx` part works well or not.

Comment: I edit with more details, hopefully serve more guides

Answer (score 2):

I think exec and those kind of functions are disabled in your php.ini . You can check it by

```
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
} else {
    echo "exec is disabled";
}
```

Open your php.ini and navigate to section disable_functions

If exec is listed under there , remove it.

Then restart `php-fpm`.

Also If Safe Mode is enabled this function will not be available. You need to disable it.

**Edit**

use full path for ping. You can find it by issuing this command in shell `which ping`

**Edit**

```
<?php
exec('/sbin/ping -c3 google.com', $output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: # which ping
/sbin/ping, changue path in my file

in browser Array ( ), in command line work fine!!

Comment: what about `exec('ls', $output);  print_r($output);`

Comment: Only show **Array ( )** , en command line work fine php myfile.php

Comment: Execute this in terminal `chmod +x /sbin/ping` and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Php-fpm is chrooted by default on OpenBSD. That's probably the cause you see it working on cli and not on web.

You've two solutions. Disable chroot (comment the line `chroot = /var/www` on `/etc/php-fpm.conf`) or fix the issues you may encounter.

A static compiled version of ping resides under `/bin/ping` (from inside the chroot). You'll need to copy `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` inside the chroot in order to resolv hosts names (as you're trying to do pinging google).
All other system commands you plan to call must be copied inside the chroot also (along with their shared libraries or compiled statically).

Use `ldd(1)` to find out which libraries you'll need.
Depending on what you're trying to achieve it could be a tedious work.

Exec, system and shell_exec are probably disabled, as other users pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
//echo "Вот-вот... ещё 1 мин";
//echo "Wait... 1 min";
echo exec('/bin/bash --login -c "cd /var/www/194.7.2.2/public && /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby work1.rb "'.$_GET['some_value']);
```

It`s worked 4me!

Comment: Just a tip: generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours debugging. this solved mines.

1. Edit `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
2. Uncomment & adjust this lines:

   env[PATH] =
   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/add_your_executable_files_path_here

   env[TMP] = /tmp

   env[TMPDIR] = /tmp

   env[TEMP] = /tmp
3. Restart php-fpm `service php7.4-fpm restart`

Environment

`nginx, php-fpm7.4, debian 9.13`